# How to change sharepoint outgoing email body

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, my-site, email-templates

our company decide to use sharepoint 2013 my site feature.

i should change the content of email body which automatically send to users.

for example there shouldn't be SharePoint word in this mail.

how can i change the content of email body. i couldn't find in resx file.

[image: my site email notification]

thanks for redirection. however i don't think so that i ask for this.

I don't want to change or make a new mail template. I want to change the content of mail body.

as i mention the first part, it should't be written a word like "SharePoint" on mail body. because my customer don't know what is "sharepoint".